# node.js - share sockets between processes

Tags: sockets, node.js

I´ve read that it´s possible to share sockets between processes. Is this also possible in Node.js?

I saw the cluster api in node.js, but that´s not what I´m looking for. I want to be able to accept a connection in one process, maybe send & read a bit, and after a while pass this socket to another fully independent node.js process.

I could already do this with piping, but I don´t want to do this, since it´s not as fast as directly reading/writing to the socket itself.

Any ideas?

**Update**
I found the following entry in the node.js documentation:

```
new net.Socket([options]) #
Construct a new socket object.

options is an object with the following defaults:

{ fd: null
  type: null
  allowHalfOpen: false
}
fd allows you to specify the existing file descriptor of socket. type specified underlying protocol. It can be 'tcp4', 'tcp6', or 'unix'. About allowHalfOpen, refer to createServer() and 'end' event.
```

I think it would be possible to set the "fd" property to the filedescriptor of the socket  and then open the socket with that. But... How can I get the filedescriptor of the socket and pass it to the process that needs it?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sharing a socket between multiple processes is asking for concurrency and locking nightmares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment, but I've added it as a feature request to the node issues page.

**Update**
In the mean time, I've written a module for this. You can find it here: https://github.com/VanCoding/node-ancillary

Comment: Do you have a link to the feature request?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take a look at [hook.io](https://github.com/hookio/hook.io)

> *hook.io is a distributed EventEmitter built on node.js. In addition to providing a minimalistic event framework, hook.io also provides a rich network of hook libraries for managing all sorts of input and output.*

Comment: hook.io is definitely not the answer to this question, it's much more than that -- and for many people it will be too much more.

Comment: Tom, agreed that it's a lot, but there should be plenty of "examples" that Van could dig into inside the implementation of it

Comment: It definately seems to be an interesting project, but it, in its core, does not what I want. I think they also pipe their data and are not able to share the same stream/socket.