# Realtime messaging with NodeJS across multiple processes

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to implement an API that interacts with a NodeJS server for realtime messaging. Now when that NodeJS app is deployed to a scalable environment like **Heroku**, multiple instances of this app may be running.

Is it possible to design the node app so that all clients subscribed to a "message channel" will receive this message, although multiple node instances are running - and therefore multiple copies of this channel?

Comment: Interesting question. Wondering if you considered a database, containing stats & whatnot, and then each process pings that now and then?

Comment: Yes, but that would defeat the realtime awesomeness of node. Would essentially be nothing more than polling.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490093/node-js-share-sockets-between-processes) may be relevant.

Comment: Check out the [node.js bindings](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:node-js) for [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/), it should provide some simple, high performance IPC abstractions to do what you want. In particular, [the pub/sub example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#header-9) will be useful.

The main challenge as I imagine it, without knowing anything about how Heroku spawns multiple server instances, will be the logic to determine who is the publisher (the rest of the instances will be subscribers).  So let's say, for argument's sake, that your hosting provider gives you an environment variable called `INSTANCE_NUM` which is an integer in `[0,1024]` indicating the instance number of the process; so we'll say that instance zero is the message publisher.

```javascript
var zmq = require('zeromq')
if (process.env['INSTANCE_NUM'] === '0') { // I'm the publisher.
  var emitter = getEventEmitter(); // e.g. an HttpServer.
  var pub = zmq.createSocket('pub');
  pub.bindSync('tcp://*:5555');
  emitter.on('someEvent', function(data) {
    pub.send(data);
  });
} else { // I'm a subscriber.
  var sub = zmq.createSocket('sub');
  sub.subscribe('');
  sub.on('message', function(data) {
    // Handle the event data...
  });
  sub.connect('tcp://localhost:5555');
}
```

Note that I'm new to zeromq and the above code is totally untested, just for demonstration.