# How to initiate a TCP socket connection and write something to it with node.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I have an open tcp on machine in my lan network on port `4028` with IP address `192.168.1.166`. I would like to connect to it with node's `net.connect` but I may be missing something here.

My code:

```
var net = require("net");

var s = new net.Socket({ 
  fd: null,
  allowHalfOpen: true,
  readable: true,
  writable: true
});

s.connect(4028, "192.168.1.166");

s.write("{\"command\":\"status\"}");

s
.on('data',function(data){
  console.log(data.toString());
  JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
})
.on('connect', function(data){
  console.log("connected!");
});
```

Error:

```
$node app.js
net.js:50
  throw new TypeError('Unsupported fd type: ' + type);
        ^
TypeError: Unsupported fd type: TTY
    at createHandle (net.js:50:9)
    at new Socket (net.js:156:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/XXXX/node/net/app.js:3:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

So far I am following up the api docs http://nodejs.org/api/net.html but I have surely missed something.

I have managed to do it with

```
var net = require("net");

var client = net.connect(4028, "192.168.1.166");


.on('data',function(data){
  console.log(data.toString());
  JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
})
.on('connect', function(data){
  console.log("connected!");
});
```

but then how do I write to it ?

Answer (score 0):

the options in `Socket` object are optional, `fd` option it isn't exactly supported in Windows.

from documentation http://nodejs.org/api/net.html

> fd allows you to specify the existing file descriptor of socket. Set
>   readable and/or writable to true to allow reads and/or writes on this
>   socket (NOTE: Works only when fd is passed).
>   About allowHalfOpen, refer to createServer() and 'end' event.

also see this

[node.js - share sockets between processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490093/node-js-share-sockets-between-processes)

the preferred way for opening connections is with

[net.createConnection](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_options_connectionlistener)

you can begin writing after the `connect` event is fired.